# Saiyan Power Levels?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I was wondering how was Gohan so much **stronger as a normal Saiyan than Goku was as SS3** when he fought Buu. Is there not like a power level to reach the next SSJ form?

[image]

Power level example:

- **10,000 to reach SS1**
- **100,000 to reach SS2**
- etc.

Why couldn't Gohan reach SS3 already?
Or he could fight as SS2 at least?

*Maybe I have to rewrite my question again:*

If you read the list below,

- SS1 is always at about 25,000,000
- SS2 is always at about 49,000,000

**If Gohan with the Mystic Sword is as strong as Goku was as SS3, there wouldn't be any difference in their strength when he would transform into SS3?**

Comment: I think I remember reading some time ago that they also have to be a pure blooded saiyan (which Gohan wasn't) to become super-saiyan 3. But this may have been pure fan speculation

Comment: @user2716766 thanks for this info, i will follow this clue :)

Comment: @user2716766 he doesn't have to be pure blooded, in later episodes, Gohan transforms in SSJ3. By the way, Goten is also not pure blooded and reaches SSJ3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a possible answer:

I found this in the [DB Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gohan) .

> As Goku, Supreme Kai, and Kibito observe what is happening down on
>   Earth, Gohan grows increasingly impatient as Old Kai reads and laughs
>   at comics instead of unlocking his power. Gohan soon loses his
>   patience and angrily powers up, displaying an amazing power that
>   illuminates the Supreme Kai planet. However, amazed at realizing that
>   some of his power really was unlocked, Gohan apologizes to Old Kai,
>   and resumes the ritual. **After some time, the ritual is finally
>   completed and Gohan is told to power up like he does for the Super
>   Saiyan transformation; however, when he does, his appearance does not
>   change, but his power and strength gain an awesome increase.** Gohan
>   says goodbye to Supreme Kai, Old Kai, and his father Goku and is
>   transported back to Earth by Kibito. Before Kibito transports back to
>   the Supreme Kai planet, Gohan asks for the clothes reminiscent of his
>   father's, to which Kibito happily complies. Kibito wishes Gohan good
>   luck and transports back to the Supreme Kai planet. With his power
>   finally released and the fate of the world now in his hands, Gohan
>   flies off to confront the new Majin Buu: Super Buu.

*So it seems when Gohan get "Mystic Gohan", even though he increased his Power his appearance didn't change. So he coulnd't transform in any other Saiyan form than the normal form, but still getting stronger.*

Answer (score 4):

[Saiyan Power Levels](http://www.danjco.com/power.htm) - check this link out.

It states the power level every character have during a specific battle.

**Majin Buu Saga**

> Fat Buu: 45,000,000
>   Majin Buu: 80,000,000
>   Good Buu: 55,000,000
>   Bad Buu: 65,000,000
>   Super Buu: 70,000,000
>   Ultimate Buu: 50,000,000
>   Majin Gotenks Buu: 90,000,000
>   Majin Vegito Buu: 100,000,000
>   Goku: 5,000,000
>   Goku (Super Saiyan): 27,000,000
>   Goku (Super Saiyan 2): 49,500,000
>   Goku (Super Saiyan 3): 79,999,999
>   Goku (Genki-dama): 100,000,000
>   Piccolo: 26,000,000
>   Gohan: 3,000,000
>   Gohan (Super Saiyan): 25,000,000
>   Gohan (with the Z sword): 53,000,000
>   Goten: 1,500,000
>   Goten (Super Saiyan): 10,000,000
>   Trunks: 1,500,000
>   Trunks (Super Saiyan): 10,000,000
>   Gotenks: 3,000,000
>   Gotenks (Super Saiyan): 20,000,000
>   Gotenks (Super saiyan 3): 75,000,000
>   Vegeta: 5,000,000
>   Vegeta (Super Saiyan): 26,500,000
>   Vegeta (Super Saiyan 2): 49,000,000
>   Vegito: 10,000,000
>   Vegito (Super Saiyan): 53,000,000
>   Vegito (Super Saiyan 2): 99,500,000

Comment: thank you very much, but that doesn't answer my question. also it doesn't show, how Gohan (3'000'000) could beat Buu (55'000'000)...

Comment: Seems a bit ambiguous, but it was Gohan with the Z-Sword ot Mystic Gohan that fought Buu.

Comment: ok so it would be Goahn (53'000'000) against Buu (65'000'000)?

Comment: The chart is just an estimate, I would take it with a grain of salt. Though the import thing here is that Super Saiyan, SS2, etc... Are based relatively off their non-SS form.

Comment: To add to this, imho Gohan in mystic form is as strong as SS3 (I think Gotenks SS3 himself said so...).. There are lots of other disparities... Piccolo for 1 is stronger than SS Goku... So these levels are just an estimate.

Comment: I am curious about Vegetto Super Saiyan 2? I remember him becoming Super saiyan but when does he go the next level?

Comment: @Dredd good question, from what I remember after fusing into Vegetto they just went from normal to "Super Vegetto"

Comment: @Yaje good answer, but I question how accurate the source is. Although I doubt there is any canon source that would state the exact/approximate power levels of everyone from DBZ anyway, so +1

Comment: In all honesty, I would not reference this site for power levels as it's inaccurate.  A perfect example is that it makes the claim that Frieza was more powerful than Broly and that Goku could not defeat Frieza in his base form by the time of the latest movie, which is absolutely inaccurate.  Another is that Gohan is weaker then Buu in his ultimate form, another falsity.  Gohan outclassed Buu and Goku in every way at this point in time.

Comment: That is a non canon reference sheet, and does not include Freiza, who was estimated at 1 million in only his second form, and over 100 million at 100% in his final form, which using these numbers means he is stronger than everyone on that list.

Answer (score 0):

As we saw more recently in Dragon Ball Super, Gohan in mystic form isnt the same as Gohan in base form. Once he got rusty, to reach mystic form he had to power up to super saiyan and super saiyan 2 first, to finally reach the mystic form transformation, which looks very similar to base form with the sole difference that he has a bang and more spiky hair.

[Gohan turns mystic again - Dragon Ball Super](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4MGSd7-46E)

Answer (score -1):

> The first Super Saiyan transformation occurs when a Saiyan who has
>   reached a very high level of power loses himself in a fit of rage.[22]
>   However, the transformation must be triggered in response to a great
>   need, an example being in Goku's case to defeat Frieza. While physical
>   change is not too drastic apart from a slight increase in muscle
>   mass,[23][24] the power output increase is colossal; the form is said
>   to multiply the Saiyan's power by 50x times its normal amount[22] (in
>   the Dragon Ball Z: The Anime Adventure Game, the multiplier for the
>   form is 2.5x the user's normal amount of power). When Goku utilises
>   the Super Saiyan form against General Rilldo in Dragon Ball GT, Rilldo
>   states that Goku's power has increased a hundredfold.

Source: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan

Comment: Welcome to Anime and manga, Could you explain your answer a bit in terms of relevance to the question rather than a copy and paste job from a wiki